# How to get maxium value of a group and corresponding value from another column of the original dataset using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis

I have a [dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QzjEYWuTmctMSHcBCbo1vGdkep0gb7qV?usp=sharing) which is:

```
fire_data <- data.frame(Year = c(2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,
2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,
2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,
2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,
2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,
2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,
2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,
2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,
2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,
2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020
),
Description.of.fire.accident.scene = c("factory-industry fire", 
"factory-industry fire", "factory-industry fire", "slum fire", 
"slum fire", "slum fire", "gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas distribution pipeline fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas cylinder fire", "gas cylinder fire", 
"gas cylinder fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "multi-storied building fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "other building fire", "other building fire", 
"other building fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", 
"hospital fire", "hospital fire", "hospital fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "KPI and govt. institute fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "education institute fire", "education institute fire", 
"education institute fire", "other scene fire", "other scene fire", 
"other scene fire", "factory-industry fire", "factory-industry fire", 
"factory-industry fire", "slum fire", "slum fire", "slum fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas distribution pipeline fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas cylinder fire", "gas cylinder fire", 
"gas cylinder fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "multi-storied building fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "other building fire", "other building fire", 
"other building fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", 
"hospital fire", "hospital fire", "hospital fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "KPI and govt. institute fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "education institute fire", "education institute fire", 
"education institute fire", "other scene fire", "other scene fire", 
"other scene fire", "factory-industry fire", "factory-industry fire", 
"factory-industry fire", "slum fire", "slum fire", "slum fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas distribution pipeline fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas cylinder fire", "gas cylinder fire", 
"gas cylinder fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "multi-storied building fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "other building fire", "other building fire", 
"other building fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", 
"hospital fire", "hospital fire", "hospital fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "KPI and govt. institute fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "education institute fire", "education institute fire", 
"education institute fire", "other scene fire", "other scene fire", 
"other scene fire"),

Type = c("male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee"
),

injured = c(35, 5, 17, 21, 8, 0, 14, 7, 0, 28, 2, 0, 5, 1, 
0, 9, 9, 4, 15, 5, 0, 28, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 35, 7, 1, 5, 2, 0, 1, 
2, 0, 101, 20, 5, 70, 39, 0, 5, 5, 0, 62, 29, 0, 59, 16, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 18, 16, 4, 47, 20, 1, 27, 7, 0, 8, 5, 0, 43, 2, 1, 11, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 10, 0, 21, 0, 0, 22, 10, 3, 30, 10, 0, 49, 
18, 0, 5, 0, 0, 10, 5, 5, 27, 20, 2, 20, 8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 24, 1, 
2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 28, 2, 0),

dead = c(47, 3, 13, 2, 4, 0, 
7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 57, 85, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 11, 1, 0, 12, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 4, 0, 4, 1, 0, 7, 5, 0, 2, 2, 0, 
6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 9, 89, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0)
)
```

My goal is to get a tibble which will show *Description.of.the.fire.scene* with the total (for all year) maximum number of *Death* of each *Type* like this photo.

[image]

Now for the data set given in the link, I at first tried this one:

```
 max_fatality <- fire_data |>
    group_by(Description.of.fire.accident.scene, Type) |>
              summarize(
                Total_fatality = sum(dead),
                ) |>
         group_by(Type) |>
        summarise(max_total_fatality = max(Total_fatality))
    max_fatality
```

Now this gives me the following tibble:

[image]

which is close to my solution by I want the corresponding *Description.of.the.fire.scene* also. So with the help of other stackoverflow questions, I improvise:

```
max_fatality <- fire_data |>
    group_by(Description.of.fire.accident.scene, Type) |>
              summarize(
                Total_fatality = sum(dead),
                ) |>
         group_by(Type) |>
              mutate(
                fatality_count = max(Total_fatality),
                new_value = Description.of.fire.accident.scene[which.max(Total_fatality)])|>
                      filter(
                        Total_fatality == fatality_count
                      ) |>
                          select(1, 2, 4)
        max_fatality
```

This gives me my expected result:
[image]

But I think my solution is very much clunky. Can you suggest me a simple solution.

Comment: please add workable data using `dput` or some sort of workable dataset (i.e., not a picture)

Comment: @BWilliams Done. Actually I didn't know how to do that. That's why I added a link to dataframe file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking to `filter` out the `max` for each category type

This code should work:

```
library(dplyr)

fire_data |> 
  summarise(max_total_fatality = sum(dead), .by = c(Description.of.fire.accident.scene, Type)) |> 
  filter(max_total_fatality == max(max_total_fatality), .by = Type)
```

```
Description.of.fire.accident.scene          Type max_total_fatality
1 factory-industry fire          male                108
2 factory-industry fire fire employee                 13
3          vehicle fire        female                 94
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the solution. It works!

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:
In case of ties you will get more lines per group like the first 3 rows:

```
library(dplyr)

fire_data %>% 
  group_by(Description.of.fire.accident.scene, Type) %>% 
  summarise(max_total_fatality = sum(dead)) %>% 
  slice_max(max_total_fatality)
```

data:

```
   Description.of.fire.accident.scene Type          max_total_fatality
   <chr>                              <chr>                      <dbl>
 1 KPI and govt. institute fire       female                         0
 2 KPI and govt. institute fire       fire employee                  0
 3 KPI and govt. institute fire       male                           0
 4 boiler fire                        male                           1
 5 education institute fire           female                         0
 6 education institute fire           fire employee                  0
 7 education institute fire           male                           0
 8 factory-industry fire              male                         108
 9 gas cylinder fire                  male                          11
10 gas distribution pipeline fire     male                          10
11 hospital fire                      male                           9
12 market-haat-bazaar-shop fire       male                          18
13 multi-storied building fire        male                           8
14 other building fire                male                          15
15 other scene fire                   male                          25
16 slum fire                          female                        10
17 slum fire                          male                          10
18 vehicle fire                       female                        94
```

```
fire_data <- structure(list(year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020
), Description.of.fire.accident.scene = c("factory-industry fire", 
"factory-industry fire", "factory-industry fire", "slum fire", 
"slum fire", "slum fire", "gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas distribution pipeline fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas cylinder fire", "gas cylinder fire", 
"gas cylinder fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "multi-storied building fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "other building fire", "other building fire", 
"other building fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", 
"hospital fire", "hospital fire", "hospital fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "KPI and govt. institute fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "education institute fire", "education institute fire", 
"education institute fire", "other scene fire", "other scene fire", 
"other scene fire", "factory-industry fire", "factory-industry fire", 
"factory-industry fire", "slum fire", "slum fire", "slum fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas distribution pipeline fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas cylinder fire", "gas cylinder fire", 
"gas cylinder fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "multi-storied building fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "other building fire", "other building fire", 
"other building fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", 
"hospital fire", "hospital fire", "hospital fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "KPI and govt. institute fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "education institute fire", "education institute fire", 
"education institute fire", "other scene fire", "other scene fire", 
"other scene fire", "factory-industry fire", "factory-industry fire", 
"factory-industry fire", "slum fire", "slum fire", "slum fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas distribution pipeline fire", 
"gas distribution pipeline fire", "gas cylinder fire", "gas cylinder fire", 
"gas cylinder fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", "boiler fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "multi-storied building fire", 
"multi-storied building fire", "other building fire", "other building fire", 
"other building fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", "vehicle fire", 
"hospital fire", "hospital fire", "hospital fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", "market-haat-bazaar-shop fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "KPI and govt. institute fire", 
"KPI and govt. institute fire", "education institute fire", "education institute fire", 
"education institute fire", "other scene fire", "other scene fire", 
"other scene fire"), Type = c("male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee", 
"male", "female", "fire employee", "male", "female", "fire employee"
), injured = c(35, 5, 17, 21, 8, 0, 14, 7, 0, 28, 2, 0, 5, 1, 
0, 9, 9, 4, 15, 5, 0, 28, 6, 3, 6, 0, 0, 35, 7, 1, 5, 2, 0, 1, 
2, 0, 101, 20, 5, 70, 39, 0, 5, 5, 0, 62, 29, 0, 59, 16, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 18, 16, 4, 47, 20, 1, 27, 7, 0, 8, 5, 0, 43, 2, 1, 11, 
4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 10, 0, 21, 0, 0, 22, 10, 3, 30, 10, 0, 49, 
18, 0, 5, 0, 0, 10, 5, 5, 27, 20, 2, 20, 8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 24, 1, 
2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 28, 2, 0), dead = c(47, 3, 13, 2, 4, 0, 
7, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 57, 85, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 11, 1, 0, 12, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 4, 0, 4, 1, 0, 7, 5, 0, 2, 2, 0, 
6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 9, 89, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -117L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Description.of.fire.accident.scene = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), injured = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), dead = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000026ef8a79610>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```